# Removing rows and sorting php mysql

Tags: jquery

I currently have a table that is sortable by columns using a page refresh with an order variable:

```
$orderBy = array('PTS', '3PT');
$order = $_GET['orderBy'];
$query="SELECT * FROM `temps` ORDER BY ".$order." ASC" ;
```

You can then remove rows by clicking a button in that row that uses jquery:

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(e){
$(this).closest('tr').remove()
}   )
```

However since it is removing HTML rows, sorting again brings back all the removed rows. What is the best way to go about this such that each user can remove rows and then sort their own table?

Comment: you probably want to sort with js as well (unless you want to permanently
delete the table rows?) - there are many scripts for this

Comment: You can use AJAX. What is the primary key for your `temps` table?

Comment: Currently it is the player's name.

Comment: You don't have a primary key (`id`) for your `temps` table?

Comment: A numeric one, hasn't been necessary so far, I can make one though, let's assume I do, The name is an id, first 5 of last, first 2 of first. ex: davisan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

First is, we have to set a value on your data. Lets enclose your data in a `<a>` entity and set a `data-artid` tags on it and assign the primary key value on it.

Lets assume you fetch all your data like this:

```
<div id="result"></div> <!-- WE CAN USE THIS LATER TO SHOW THE STATUS OF THE DELETED DATA -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a data-artid="1">Data 1</a></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a data-artid="2">Data 2</a></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a data-artid="3">Data 3</a></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete">
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then lets create a script that will get the value of the closest data of the clicked `Delete button`. Then use AJAX to pass it on a separate file to do the delete query.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */
   $('input[type="button"]').click(function(e){ /* WHEN A DELETE BUTTON IS CLICKED */

      e.preventDefault(); /* PREVENT THE DEFAULT ACTION */
      var deleteid = $(this).closest('tr').find('a').attr('data-artid'); /* GET THE VALUE OF THE NEAREST DATA OF THE CLICKED DELETE BUTTON */
      var dataString = "delete-id=" + deleteid; /* STORE IT IN A DATA STRING */
      $(this).closest('tr').remove(); /* REMOVE THE ROW */

      $.ajax({ /* START AJAX */
        type: "POST", /* METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
        url: "delete.php", /* FILE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
        data: dataString, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING TO delete.php */
        success: function(result){ /* WHEN ACTION IS SUCCESS */
          $("#result").html(result); /* SHOW TO THIS DIV THE RESULT */
        }
      }) /* END OF AJAX */

   });
});
```

You can check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/kz8670o4/), but without the ajax part.

You'll notice that we pass the data to `delete.php`. We have to create the delete query in this file (*Note that this will permanently delete this record*).

delete.php:

```
<?php

  /* INCLUDE YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION HERE */    

  if(!empty($_POST["delete-id"])){
    $stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM temps WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_result("i",$_POST["delete-id"]);
    $stmt->execute();
  }

  else {
    echo "You have not selected a data to delete.";
  }

?>
```

But if you want to retain the data, we can add a scheme to your table structure.

We can create a table, lets name it `preference-tb`. This table will store the following

- a primary key (`pre-id`)
- user's id (`users-id`)
- the id of the data that the user prefers to hide (`data-id`)
- and the type of sort where the user want to hide the data (`order`)

So, our `delete.php` will not be totally be a delete query, but an update/insert query.

Comment: _What is the best way to go about this such that each user can remove rows and then sort their own table?_ So it looks like author doesn't want the rows to be deleted from DB

Comment: I figured out the sorting with JS mentioned earlier, this actually works better for how I wanted to expand my site though. Thank you!